# How to combine these two ffmpeg commands so that no intermediate file gets generated?

Tags: ffmpeg, video

I need to concat two files with this command.

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:04 -to 1:15:28 -i 1_out.mp4 -ss 0:42 -to 10:28 -i 2.mp4 -lavfi concat=n=2:a=1 result.mp4
```

However, I need to scale `1.mp4` before the concatenation to get `1_out.mp4`.

```
ffmpeg -to 2:00 -i 1.mp4 -vf "scale=1920:1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1920:1080:-1:-1:color=black" 1_out.mp4
```

As you can see, I have two commands and `1_out.mp4` in the intermediate file. How can I combine these two commands so that no intermediate file gets generated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-filter_complex` is your friend

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:04 -to 1:15:28 -i 1_out.mp4 \
       -ss 0:42 -to 10:28 -i 2.mp4 \
       -filter_complex \
           "[0:v:0]scale=1920:1080:\
                force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,\
            pad=1920:1080:-1:-1:color=black[vscaled],\
            [vscaled][0:a:0][1:v:0][1:a:0]\
                concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[outv][outa]" \ 
       -map [outv] -map [outa] result.mp4
```

I haven't tested the full command, but this is the idea. `[0:v:0]` is the first video stream of the first file (remember that all numberings starts at 0 in ffmpeg), it is input (and only it) to the scale and pad filters, and the result is named `[vscaled]` (your choice). Then `[vscaled]` is used as input to the concat filter along with `[1:v:0]` (the first video stream of the second file) and the audio streams. The result is named `[outv]` (your choice again) for the concatenated video stream and `[outa]` for the the concatenated audio stream. And `[outv]` and `[outa]` are finally mapped to the output file.

Otherwise, you may investigate using pipes (the first ffmpeg writes the output to the standard output, which is piped to second ffmpeg, which reads one of the files from the standard input. Still two separate commands, but no intermediate file).

Comment: Thank you so much my friend!

Comment: Hi PierU, could you explain a little on this part: `[vscaled][0:a:0][1:v:0][1:a:0]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[outv][outa]`? As I understand, the input to `concat` are : scaled video, input 1 audio, input 2 video, input 2 audio. So concat will make a video (that has audio) from "scaled video, input 1 audio", and one from "input 2 video, input 2 audio"? What does `concat=n=2:v=1:a=1` mean?

Comment: @FajelaTajkiya The concat syntax here means that there are 2 segments to concatenate (n=2), and that in the output of the filter you want 1 video stream (v=1) and 1 audio stream (a=1). In some cases for instance you would like to have to 2 audio streams in the output, and you would code something like `[vscaled][0:a:0][0:a:1][1:v:0][1:a:0][1:a:1]concat=n=2:v=1:a=2[outv][outa0][outa1]`

Comment: Thanks again bro!